# How do you limit list objects template side, rather than view side

Tags: django, django-templates

One of the ways to limit objects is to add a limitation to a function like this

```
def ten_objects():
    obj = Model.objects.all()[0:10]  # limit to 10
    return {'objects': obj}
```

However how do you achieve this inside a template rather than inside a view?

I know you can filter through objects within a template and limit characters but how do you actually limit the amount of objects displayed in a loop. Via the template. for example the following code will loop through all objects....

```
    <ul>
     {% for new in news %}
      <li>
       <p>{{ news.title }}</p>
       <p>{{ news.body }}</p>
      </li>
     {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

How do I break the loop, say after the firs 3 objects/items? And how do I do it inside the template?

Comment: <a href="http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice">`slice`</a>

Answer (score 192, accepted):

There is a [`slice`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) filter that you can use in templates. This works exactly the same as slicing within the view.

```
{% for new in news|slice:":10" %}
```

Comment: If you have a scenario  where you are using `{% for object  in user.objects.all %}`   you can use `{% for object  in user.objects.all|slice:":10" %}`

Comment: please give me the slice documentation link of django.

Comment: It's literally linked from my answer above.

Comment: I got that @Daniel. I search slice in github django repository but i find slice_filter not slice .

Comment: Working for me.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - do you happen to know alternative to queryset.0.attribute in templates, I am using it and it seems like there should be better way to do it, accesing random items by index.. without the for loop, or maybe I should check the queryset class internals

Answer (score 13):

You want to use the [slice](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) template filter

Here's your example altered to use it:

```
<ul>
{% for new in news|slice:":3" %}
<li>
<p>{{ new.title }}</p>
<p>{{ new.body }}</p>
</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: I know I'm kind of nagging, but it should be:
`{{ new.title}}` and  `{{ new.body }}`

Comment: this is a more complete code example than the accepted answer, this is a more helpful answer, so I upvoted and am explaining why