# Django Templates: How best can the output of executing python code in a Django template be suppressed?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Someone has probably encountered this before, and perhaps even the docs provide a solution already, but I couldn't find it yet. My situation is this:

Just to illustrate the REAL PROBLEM: Assuming I have a list that I pass to the template, and which list I iterate over, with a `{% for...` in one instance, and in the other, I only need to display its first 5 elements only (based on some condition for example, and not just the first 5 elements of the list). Both loops are being used to output a table dynamically. Now, it's the second instance that's tricky... I adopted [the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8671715/522150), which utilizes a special Counter Class, passed to the template context, and on which one must invoke the `Counter.increment` method, to be able to increment the counter - which I then use in my conditional statement, to halt execution of the loop.

The challenge:

I currently have code like this:

```
<script>{{ Counter.reset }}</script>
<table>
...
{% for l in list %}
{%if Counter.counter <= 5 %}
<tr><td>{{ l.some_field }} <span style="display:none">{{ Counter.increment }}</span></td></tr>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

So, how can I just call the `Counter.increment` method, without needing the `<span>` inside which I encapsulate it (so the output from that code isn't sent to the browser)? Is it okay to just do:

```
<tr><td>{{ l.some_field }}{{ Counter.increment }}</td></tr>
```

The above would work, if `Counter.increment` doesn't return anything, but what if it does?!

**How best can the output of executing python code in a Django template be suppressed then?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you limit list objects template side, rather than view side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907628/how-do-you-limit-list-objects-template-side-rather-than-view-side)

Comment: @solarissmoke the limiting aspect of my problem is just a scenario I'm using to illustrate the real problem - which is: *How best can the output of executing python code in a Django template be suppressed?* This question stands unsolved, whether we are talking about the output of `Counter.increment` or some other arbitrary method call or variable output.

Comment: My advice on that front would be that if you find yourself doing complex logic like this at template level, you need to rethink it and find a way to do the logic in your view (or in a template tag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you can use `with` tag and ignore variable:

```
{% with ignorevar=Counter.increment %}{% endwith %}
```

Comment: This is neat. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a hack, but it would solve your problem:

```
{{ Counter.increment|yesno:"," }}
```

(See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#yesno) on the `yesno` filter)

Comment: This is a clever hack indeed, but me wonders (as it's not documented, and I haven't tried it yet), would the `yesno` filter allow the "empty" alternatives? Otherwise, this seems like it.. and also very close to what I was already trying to do.

Comment: I see no reason why it shouldn't work with "empty" values. All values are truthy or falsy in Python.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the top five elements, then I think the right way is to **send a list** of only top 5 elements from your views to your your html templates in the very first place.

Also, if for some reason, you are not able to do that, then you should there is a thing in Django known as **Template Tags** where you do all your calculations.

See this -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/

And finally if you still want to use Counter.increment, then simply put it inside a div say "count-flag" and using your javascript, hide that div forever on page load:

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
    $("#count-flag").hide();
}
```

So it will not be displayed on your html, but technically this is not the way to do it.

Comment: In the question, I indicate that I use the same list in two places - within the same template, and so, it would be redundant to send in two lists, even though I know I could, thus, my need to find an elegant way to halt the iteration in the second use-case. As for suppression of the output, I already use an inline-css rule for that - check my code please. So, I don't see your solution as any better than what I'm already doing.

Comment: If you are using the same list in two places, then you don't need to send it TWICE. Obviously it won't be consumed when it will be used for the first time.
Secondly, as I mentioned in my answer, for doing calculations in HTML, there is something known as TemplateTags in Django whose link I provided you. GO through it and hopefully it will give you a better approach to address your problem.

Comment: So, going the template tag way, perhaps a filter that does something like `{{ Object.method_producing_output| suppress }}` is what you are talking about? Or a *real* template tag, such as `{% suppressed %}{{ Object.method_producing_output }}{% endsuppressed %}`. I could write such solutions, but wonder if the built-ins already provide such mechanisms, as this seems to be to be a fairly typical scenario to bump into...

Comment: I was talking about the first one.
And if you are doing very few no. of calculations then you may do it in your html only, but if there are complex calculations, as you replied to solarissmoke that you've merely given an example in your question and that there might be other logic and calculations in the loop as well, then in that case, we go for templatetags. I mean that's why they were introduced for in the very first place, as you don't want to do time consuming calculations on your frontend as it will slow down your page loads
So just like you load your static_files, you load the filters