# how to iterate python-django loop for N times in template?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-oscar

I have an Object in python-django which i want to iterate in Django template for 5 times only, but the object has more than 100 values in it.

What i am doing is :

```
  {% for x in abc %}
     <h4>{{x.name}}</h4>    
  {% endfor %}
```

nut this will run run till all elements. want to run it 5 times only.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907628/how-do-you-limit-list-objects-template-side-rather-than-view-side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the built-in 'slice' template tag:

```
{% for x in abc|slice:":5" %}
   <h4>{{x.name}}</h4>    
{% endfor %}
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#slice