# Django how to limit template to only two posts

Tags: django

i would like to only show the last two posts added on the template (preferably the ones posted today only), i have seen this being done but not on class based views.

```
from .forms import PostForm
from .models import Post
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.views import generic
from django.urls import reverse_lazy


class homeView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'MAG-page.html'
```

MAG-page.html

```
{% for post in object_list %}
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">


        <div>
        <!--Image-->
        <div class="view overlay rounded z-depth-1-half mb-3">
          <img src="{{post.Thumbnail.url}}" class="img-fluid" >
          <a>
            <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
          </a>
        </div>

        <!--Excerpt-->
        <div class="news-data">
          <a href="" class="light-blue-text">
            <h6>
              <i class="fas fa-plane"></i>
              <strong> {{post.author}}</strong>
            </h6>
          </a>
          <p>
            <strong>
              <i class="far fa-clock"></i> {{post.Date}}</strong>
          </p>
        </div>
        <h3>
          <a>
            <strong>{{post.title|safe}}</strong>
          </a>
        </h3>
        <p> {{post.Text|safe}}</p>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is probably duplicate of following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907628/how-do-you-limit-list-objects-template-side-rather-than-view-side. Answer is to add `slice` django template tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you limit list objects template side, rather than view side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907628/how-do-you-limit-list-objects-template-side-rather-than-view-side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a queryset and limit it to 2 objects.

```
class YourView(ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.order_by('-date')[:2] # replace 'date' if it does not match your case
    # other attributes/methods
```